# pygame: current time millis and delta time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

As you can see in the below code I have a basic timer system

```
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Create an instance of the Game class
game = space_world.SpaceWorld()

# Main game loop
while not done:
    # Process events (keystrokes, mouse clicks, etc)
    done = game.process_events()

    # Update object positions, check for collisions...
    game.update()

    # Render the current frame
    game.render(screen)

    # Pause for the next frame
    clock.tick(30)
```

My question is, how can I get the current time milli seconds and how do I create delta time, so I can use it in the update method ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the documentation: [`pygame.time.Clock.get_time`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.get_time) will return the number of milliseconds between the previous two calls to `Clock.tick`.

There is also [`pygame.time.get_ticks`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) which will return the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called.

Delta-time is simply the amount of time that passed since the last frame, something like:

```
t = pygame.time.get_ticks()
# deltaTime in seconds.
deltaTime = (t - getTicksLastFrame) / 1000.0
getTicksLastFrame = t
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting the exception. I tried to make my sprite shoot every 0.5s in this code:               if pygame.time.get_time - self.last_fire_projectile < 500:
                   return

self.last_fire_projectile = pygame.time.get_time But I get this error AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get_time'

Comment: @Xerath You need to call `get_time` on your `Clock` object, rather than from the `time` module.

Answer (score 15):

```
ms = clock.tick(30)
```

The function returns milliseconds since the previous call.